# Data not inserted to db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to insert data to my db using Spring,Hibernate,JPA .But when I try to insert data it does not give any errors. But data has not been inserted as well. Any ideas ?

MY persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="GuestbookPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <class>com.sanja.test.myDao.entity.User</class>


    <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="welcome"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sanjaya"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

bean declaration in service project(spring_service.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd

">

    <import  resource="classpath:spring_dao.xml"/>
    <bean id="app" class="com.sanja.test.myService.App"/>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
         p:persistenceUnitName="GuestbookPU"/>

</beans>
```

bean declaration in dao project(spring_dao.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd

">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sanja.test.myDao" />
    <context:annotation-config />


</beans>
```

My entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;
String name;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

My Test class

```
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_service.xml");
        App app=(App)context.getBean("app");
        app.addUser();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void addUser(){

         User user=new User();
         user.setName("Sanja ela");
         userDao.save(user);
             System.out.println("elane");

    }
}
```

My Dao logic

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

     public User save(User user){

        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user;

    }


}
```

I posted each and every code.

Comment: In which class you  write database insert query?

Comment: @IrenPatel I updated that code now.At the bottom in my post

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage In your test class add `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)` and see whether you are able to persist record in database.

Comment: @TransactionConfiguration is for testing purposes I guess. I can not use that

Comment: What do the logs say? Does it show if it's commiting to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Propagation.SUPPORTS`. If the transaction do not exists, the operation will be non transactional (see [javadoc for Propagation.SUPPORTS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#SUPPORTS)).

> Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none exists.

Give it a try using `Propagation.REQUIRED`([javadoc for Propagation.REQUIRED](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED));

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

Comment: I used Propagation.REQUIRED as well. But no progress :( , Thanks for the idea anyway

Comment: Don't forget the `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your context configuration.

Comment: @EG thanks friend, I added it and that problem resolved I guess,But it gives me some other problems,anyway here is my upvote for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this line?
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)

We've had problems with it sometimes. Depending on the DB configuration, sometimes it won't do commit.
It says in [the doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

> Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none
>   exists

So maybe you need to wrap it within another transactional call, or change it to another type, REQUIRED for instance.

Comment: I used Propagation.REQUIRED as well. But no progress :( , Thanks for the idea anyway