# Spring Data Jpa MVC - data not inserting, but persists during Test

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

My problem is quite the other way round, most questions here are for test data not being inserted, mine persists in tests but not when called thru the controller.

I'm still new at this so may have made some silly mistakes. Any help is appreciated!

This is my setup.

**Project 1**: Business Logic Layer: Entities, Services, Repo (Spring Data), Oracle => bll.jar (Test saves, can see insert statements in log). Files: AppConfig, HibernateConfig, PersistenceConfig

**Project 2**: Spring MVC 4.3.3, Thymeleaf 3, import bll.jar, controller calls BLL Service to save. No insert statements in log, just select statements. Oracle sequence number being incremented. The returned object after save() shows the new object with new Id. No error. Deployed in JBoss Wildfly.

**What I tried so far**

1. Thinking it must be a commit or flush issue, added saveAndFlush() in repo and service. Works in BLL Test but when called from MVC it gives error *No transaction is in progress*.
2. Checked MVC save() and looked for bindingResult errors, there were none
3. Log seems to show transaction commit so don't know why it isn't persisting
4. Added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) above my controller save() following [Data not inserted to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856427/data-not-inserted-to-db) but no effect

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value="/create", params={"save"}) //
public String save(final Cat cat
            , final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        logger.info(bindingResult.getAllErrors().toString());
        return "cat/create";
    }       
    Cat updatedCat = catService.save(cat); //saveAndFlush       
    model.clear();
    return "redirect:/cat/create";      
}
```

> **Edit 1**
>
> Note my controller does not have @Transaction, just my BLL Service
>   method
>
> Also, my entity Cat has related entities but I omited for brevity

**Service**

```
@Transactional
public Cat save(Cat cat){
    return catRepo.save(cat);
}
```

**Relevant log**

> 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG SQL:109 - select catdts0_.CAT_ID as
>   CAT_ID6_0_0_, .. from CAT_DT catdts0_ where
>   catdts0_.CAT_ID=? 2017-02-27 08:52:22 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding
>   parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [1] .. 2017-02-27 08:52:22 TRACE
>   BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([CAT_ID6_0_0_] : [NUMERIC]) - [1]
>   2017-02-27 08:52:22 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value
>   ([ID1_1_0_] : [NUMERIC]) - [1] 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG
>   EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager 2017-02-27
>   08:52:22 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager:759 - Initiating
>   transaction commit 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG
>   HibernateTransactionManager:580 - Committing Hibernate transaction on
>   Session
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@63cd240d
>   updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6262ff06
>   deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72d1cb79
>   orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3ff23a08
>   collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35158cb7
>   collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@407acfdc
>   collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3c0c4ea9
>   collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1200015a
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
>   2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:222 - Resetting read-only
>   flag of JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1dfb6d07]
>   2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager:669 - Closing
>   Hibernate Session
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@63cd240d
>   updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6262ff06
>   deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72d1cb79
>   orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3ff23a08
>   collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@35158cb7
>   collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@407acfdc
>   collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3c0c4ea9
>   collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1200015a
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after
>   transaction 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1251 -
>   Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@13f5fc54] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG
>   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource:440 - No properties file found
>   for [/resources/i18n/messages_en_GB] - neither plain properties nor
>   XML 2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG
>   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource:410 - Re-caching properties for
>   filename [/resources/i18n/messages_en] - file hasn't been modified
>   2017-02-27 08:52:22 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully
>   completed request

If I missed any important info then let me know what to post, I'm still groping in the dark.

Comment: Are you sure your configuration for your application is setting up transaction management where-as perhaps your test configuration is?

Comment: Thanks @Naros, your comment was helpful. Although I had just one context, turned out my config was messed up. Posting a solution, in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, with help from @Naros

Turns out my PersistenceConfig was messed up.

PersistenceConfig

```
public class PersistenceConfig {
    ...

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false); //was true
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ae.tbits.atn.aiwacore.common.model");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Had 2 transactionManager(), I suspect one was called in Test while the other in my web controller. Removed the below to solve the problem.

```
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s)
```